# API automation for an OKTA application

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate APIs an OKTA application. But I am unable to fetch the access token after logging into application. I tried to access the performance logs for the browser session but I am getting below error

```sh
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: log type 'performance' not found
```

I am not suing RemoteWebDriver but using pure ChromeDriver  object

Please help me understand how I can fetch the access token so that I can use it in subsequent API testing

Comment: you need to post your code to better understand what is not working for you.
According to the error your Webdriver does not have access to chrome browser performance log.
One of the possible solutions would be:
op = ChromeOptions()
op.set_capability("goog:loggingPrefs", {"browser": "ALL"})